# To Disable the multimedia contents in IE

Tags: c++, visual-studio, internet-explorer, visual-c++

I need to disable the multimedia contents in IE Programatically. Is there any way my programming environment is VC++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean here.

[MSDN has the registry settings for various IE options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980058%28PROT.13%29.aspx) (such as ShowPictures)

This page shows an example of creating a web browser control with extremely fine grained settings:

- [The most complete C# Webbrowser wrapper control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx?msg=2623195)